# Constrain toggle effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've put this jQuery together, when the document is ready the `div` with a class of `bio.read_more` is hidden.

The default behaviour for the `a` tag is removed with `e.preventDefault`

When `btn.expand_bio` is clicked `bio.read_more` is displayed.

The only problem is **all** the `bio.read_more` divs are displayed? I only want the one that's related to expand. Can anyone help?

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".bio.read_more").hide(); 

   $(".btn.expand_bio").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(".bio.read_more").toggle();
   });

 });
```

(update) Added HTML

```
   <div class="bio intro">
   <p>Intro paragraph</p>
   <a class="btn expand_bio" href="#">Read more</a>
   </div>
   <div class="bio read_more">
   <p>Expanded text here</p>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this` as reference to the element being clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".bio.read_more").hide();
    $(".btn.expand_bio").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.bio.intro').next('.read_more').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: That was quick! I thought the solution might be related to using `$(this)` but I wasn't sure how to implement it... Still not if I'm honest.

Comment: Works great thanks, I understand how that works too. Thank you for taking a look at this, really appreciate it.

Comment: @StephenMeehan glad to havelped :)